# How to solve SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@RegNo" in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Student(@RegNo,@Name,@Address,@CreatedTime) values(@RegNo,@Name,@Address,Getdate())");
```

here it display an error like SqlException:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@RegNo".

what to do? Thanks

Comment: You need to specify the parameters values. See an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/40050820/2946329

Comment: how to solve that duplication?

Comment: It should be `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Student(RegNo,Name,Address,CreatedTime) values(@RegNo,@Name,@Address,Getdate())")`

Comment: just because question sounds the same doesnt mean it is a duplicate, care to look at the answers next time?

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
  try {
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Student(RegNo,Name,Address,CreatedTime)values(@RegNo,@Name,@Address,Getdate())", con)) {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", RegNo.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address.Text);
        con.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    //handle exception..
    throw;
  }
}
```

It displays an error:

> No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
>   to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type. this error encountered after trying this code. what to do?

Comment: please share your full code

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", your textbox value); //regno.Text

Comment: use above edited code

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain why did you get the error.

Your sql command is this: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Student(@RegNo,@Name,@Address,@CreatedTime) values(@RegNo,@Name,@Address,Getdate())");`

**This means you are telling sql to execute query that is equivalent to this:**

`insert into Student(@RegNo,@Name,@Address,@CreatedTime) values(1234,'name value','address value',GetDate()) -- i've put some vlaues for example`

As you can see this is not correct.

When executing `insert` query, you want to specify column **names** and **values**, names goes into first bracket and values into second after `Values` keyword, so logically there is no column name **"@RegNo"** or **"@Name"** instead use real column names as specified in database **"RegNo"**, **"Name"**, so the query should look like this:

`insert into Student(RegNo,Name,Address,CreatedTime) values(1234,'name value','address value',GetDate())`

**Why the error message?**

In sql variables are declared with `@` prefix  for example: `declare @a int=5;` so, when trying to execute your query `insert into Student(@RegNo,.......`  `sql` recognizes `@RegNo` as variable, since declaration can't be found you get an error message

> Must declare the scalar variable @RegNo.

You should use '@' only to specify parameters not for column names

Try this in your c# code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Student(RegNo,Name,Address,CreatedTime) values(@RegNo,@Name,@Address,@CreatedTime)");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", "object value");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "object value");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", "object value");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", "object value");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedTime", DateTime.Now);  //replaced GetDate with DateTime.Now
```

!Note:  When using `SqlCommand` you can always execute query in `sql` first, to see that you didn't made some mistake

Answer (score 1):

Sql insert query has basically 2 parts.

1) Table ColumnNames for inserting values into

2) Actual values being inserted or @parameters having values.

Your SQL is mixing 1 with 2.

So instead of

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Student(@RegNo,@Name,@Address,@CreatedTime) values(@RegNo,@Name,@Address,Getdate())");
```

**It should be**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Student(RegNo,-[Name],Address,CreatedTime) values(@RegNo,@Name,@Address,Getdate())");
```

After this you only need to add all `@variables` in the `SqlCommand` object. I can see others have already suggested you  code for that.

Comment: just to add that you don't necessarily need to specify table column names if your query affects all columns

Comment: @Yollo but that will fail if we have one Identity column. So specifying column names will be good in that case.