# Taking same column but different values from database in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am trying to get top `3` safety data row according to `equipment` and `plant` selection from database. Now I could get top 3 safety value from database with equipment and plant selection and insert to textbox.

When I wrote `"' or Safety '" + textbox.text +` it is getting *other plant* and equipment selections

```cs
sqlcon1.Open();

SqlDataAdapter Data = new SqlDataAdapter (@"select * from ****** Where " 
    + "[Equipment Type]='" + equipmenttype_combobox.Text.Trim() 
    + "' and Plant='"   + plant_combobox.Text.Trim() 
    + "' and Safety= '" + firstsafety_textbox.Text.Trim() 
    + "' or Safety='"   + secondsafety_textbox.Text.Trim() 
    + "' or Safety='"   + thirdsafety_textbox.Text.Trim() + "'", sqlcon);

DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter db1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
Data.Fill(dt1);

datagridview1.DataSource = dt1;

sqlcon1.Close();
```

Comment: put query on string variable and then debug it and check what values going to concate

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683.

Comment: Side Note: you should always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection. Example https://stackoverflow.com/a/40050820/2946329

Comment: Could you give some detail ? How should I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep your sql been **readable** with a help of *verbatim strings* and *string interpolation* and many an error will be evident. Here you should either wrap `Safety = ... or Safety = ...` in parenthesis `(Safety = ... or Safety = ... )` or use `in` construction `Safety in (...)`.

Quick but **dirty** amendment is

```
...
string sql = $@"select * 
                  from Makerinfo 
                 where [Equipment Type] = '{equipmenttype_combobox.Text.Trim()}' 
                   and [Plant]          = '{plant_combobox.Text.Trim()}'
                   and [Safety]       in ('{firstsafety_textbox.Text.Trim()}', 
                                          '{secondsafety_textbox.Text.Trim()}', 
                                          '{thirdsafety_textbox.Text.Trim()}')";

SqlDataAdapter Data = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlcon1);

...
```

However, this implementation has *at least* `3` **flaws:**

1. It's prone to *SQL Injection*
2. It will *crash* on `equipmenttype_combobox.Text = "Browns' equipment"` (note *apostroph*)
3. For different plants, you have *different queries* which should be *parsed*, *optimized* etc.

Much better aproach is *parametrized query*:

```
...

string sql = $@"select * 
                  from Makerinfo 
                 where [Equipment Type] = @prm_Equipment 
                   and [Plant]          = @prm_Plant
                   and [Safety]       in (@prm_Safety_1, @prm_Safety_2, @prm_Safety_3)";

using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlcon1)) {
  // I don't know the underlying RDMBS types, that's why I've put AddWithValue
  //TODO: change AddWithValue to Add and provide the right rdbms type 
  // Something (and most probably) like
  //  q.Parameters.Add("@prm_Equipment", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
  //    plant_combobox.Text.Trim();
  q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Equipment", equipmenttype_combobox.Text.Trim());
  q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Plant",     plant_combobox.Text.Trim());
  q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Safety_1",  firstsafety_textbox.Text.Trim());
  q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Safety_2",  secondsafety_textbox.Text.Trim());
  q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_Safety_3",  thirdsafety_textbox.Text.Trim());  

  using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Load(reader);
    datagridview1.DataSource = dt1;
  }
}

...
```